# Nunit test fails in Team City but works in Visual Studio. Unable to find assembly , Where are the DLL's?

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, selenium-webdriver, nunit, teamcity

Team City asks for a Location where it can find assemblies , I was looking through my project in the local in the bin/Release and the bin/Debug folders they seem to be empty. Something similar is happening on the TeamCity machine too. Please let me know if this is storing the DLL's in another location.

Comment: Are you building the project first?

Comment: Could it be that you are using local references (e.g. SDKs) that are not installed on the TeamCity server? Check your reference paths and make sure you're not referencing something like "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs+\...\..." etc

Comment: Did you check the build output folder in your project settings? In VS right click on the project, select properties, click on the build tab, and then look at the output path.  Also check if you are building in debug mode vs release mode.  I normally change the output path of all my projects to be in a common folder outside of the source tree so they are easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misconception : I was thinking there would be multiple dll's for multiple tests but apparently there is just one , and I found it in the bin/Debug foler.